# SSRS - Count values in a column based upon distinct values in another column in SharePoint List

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, reporting-services

We have SharePoint list which has, say, two columns. Column A and Column B.

```
Column A can have three values - red, blue & green.

Column B can have four values - pen, marker, pencil & highlighter.
```

A typical view of list can be:

```
Column A - Column B
red  - pen
red - pencil
red - highlighter
blue - marker
blue - pencil
green - pen
green - highlighter
red  - pen
blue - pencil
blue - highlighter
blue - pencil
```

We are looking to create a report from SharePoint List using SSRS which has following view:

```
            red     blue   green
pen         2       0      1
marker      0       1      0
pencil      1       3      0
highlighter 1       1      1
```

We tried Sum but not able to display in single row.

Comment: add a calculated field with just the value "1", and do the sum on that field. Or use COUNT instead of SUM

Comment: @mxix - Thanks for the reply. Can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **matrix** to easily achieve this.

Use Column A (red, blue, green) for column grouping

and

Use Column B (pen, marker, pencil..) for row grouping

And your expression for detail textbox would be something like this:

```
=SUM(IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!ColumnA.VALUE) OR ISNOTHING(Fields!ColumnB.VALUE), 0, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. Can you please guide me to resource which can help in implementing **matrix**

Comment: Matrix and tablix are similar only difference is matrix has column grouping. You can right click on your report and insert the matrix object. Here is a link about matrix. technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms157334(v=SQL.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked :)
Just need to add that we user count.

Count(Fields!ColumnA.Value)